# How to assign Image Resource to ImageView with String in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, imageview

I am trying to create a routine that will assign a card image to an ImageView without using something like this: R.drawable.card_10clover. I would prefer to use a string, but the way I'm doing it doesn't work.

```
String imgRes = "R.drawable.card_";
int num = 10;
imgRes += "10";
String suit = "clover";
imgRes += "suit;
ImageView card = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgcard);
card.setImageResource(imgRes);
```

Unfortunately setImageResource only takes an int.  Please help.

Thank you,
Jack Blue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage); 
Your imgRes does not need the prefix R.drawable

```
String imgRes = "card_";
int num = 10;
imgRes += "10";
String suit = "clover";
imgRes += "suit;
ImageView card = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgcard);
int resourceId = getResource().getIdentifier (imgRes, "drawable", "com....");
card.setImageResource(resourceId);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked real well. In order to get the above code to work, I needed to make it: getResources().getIdentifier (....);  I wanted to make a different class(that extends object) do this, so I just passed the resources that getResources returns. Thanks again.